# R function to bind_rows the results of another function

Tags: r, function, dictionary, for-loop

I try to write a function for custom tables with one or more column variables. I realised it for tables with one variable:
[image: Example of a table (in german)].

Now I try to implement a function to get a custom table for a set of variables with for instance means and multiple column tables. My Problem is to bind them together.

This is, what I have:

```
library(tidyverse)

## at first some example data:

dv1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1) # dependent variable 1
dv2 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1) # dependent variable 2
iv1 <- c("m", "f", "f", "m", "m") # independent variable 1
iv2 <- c(30, 40, 30, 40, 40) # independent variable 2
iv3 <- c("b", "c", "b", "a", "a") # ...

DATA <- data_frame(iv1, iv2, iv3, dv1, dv2) # build data frame

# the help function

cross_fun <- function(.data, DV, IV = IVs, fn = ~ mean(.x)) {

   df <- .data   %>% 
      select(all_of({{ IV }}), {{ DV }})  %>% 
    mutate(var = "dv") %>% # here I would like to have the {{ DV }} Argument as values of var, but mutate(var = {{ DV }}) or mutate (var = quote(DV)) does'nt work
    mutate(across(all_of({{IV}}), as.character)) # for using it in "names_from" in pivot_wider

  LIST <- list() # define a list

  for (i in 1:(ncol(df)-2)) { # -1 for the DV
    LIST[[i]] <- df %>% select(i, {{ DV }}, var)
  }
  dt <- purrr::map(
  .x = LIST,
  .f = ~ tidyr::pivot_wider(.x, names_from = 1, values_from = 2, values_fn = fn)
                  ) %>%
    purrr::reduce(left_join, by ="var")

  return(dt)
}

# What I can do
## simple custom table

DATA %>% cross_fun(dv1, IV = c('iv3', 'iv1', 'iv2'))  

## or I use a set (IVs is standard in cross_fun) in multiple tables 
IVs <- c('iv3', 'iv1', 'iv2')

DATA %>% cross_fun(dv2)

## I can change the Variables for the columns and the function
DATA %>% 
  cross_fun(dv2, IV = c('iv3', 'iv1', 'iv2'), fn = ~sum(.x))

## now I try to bind them together in a way, that I can use it later in another function
List_2 <- list()

## I could write it in a List_2 ...
List_2[[1]] <- DATA %>% cross_fun(dv1)

# ... for every variable ...
List_2[[2]] <- DATA %>% cross_fun(dv2)

# ... and bind the rows
List_2 %>% 
  bind_rows()

# here comes my Problem, it doesn't work in my try with for loop ...
for (i in c('dv1', 'dv2')) { 
  Liste2[[i]] <- DATA %>% 
    cross_fun(DATA[[i]])
}

# or with map
DATA %>% 
  map(.x = c(dv1:dv2), .f = ~cross_fun(.x)) %>% # the cross_fun-function for more than one dependent variable
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

First, an answer: `purrr::map_dfr` automatically row-binds its results, and you should specify it like this:

```
map_dfr(c("dv1", "dv2"), cross_fun, .data = DATA)

# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   var       b     c     a     m     f  `30`  `40`
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 dv        1     0   0.5 0.667   0.5     1 0.333
# 2 dv        1     0   1   1       0.5     1 0.667
```

**Critique**

There are a few issues in your code, several having to do with passing incorrect arguments. e.g., your `for` loop is passing `DATA[[i]]` to `DV` instead of simply `i`; this passes the actual vector of values from `DATA[["dv1"]]`, instead of just the name `"dv1"`, which is what your function expects.

The following fixes this:

```
List_2 <- list()

# `i` is confusing because the loop iterates over characters, not integers;
# use something like `varname` instead
for (varname in c('dv1', 'dv2')) { 
  List_2[[varname]] <- DATA %>% 
    cross_fun(varname)
}
bind_rows(List_2)

# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   var       b     c     a     m     f  `30`  `40`
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 dv        1     0   0.5 0.667   0.5     1 0.333
# 2 dv        1     0   1   1       0.5     1 0.667
```

Your `map` call has two issues. One, you're not passing `DATA` to `cross_function()`; you're just instead passing `.x` to the `.data` argument and nothing to the other args. Two, you're trying to pass `DV` as a symbol instead of character. While this is possible, it's tricky (and trying to iterate over symbols using `map` makes it trickier), and your code isn't set up to handle it correctly.

The following fixes this:

```
map(c("dv1", "dv2"), .f = ~ cross_fun(DATA, .x)) %>% 
  bind_rows() 

# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   var       b     c     a     m     f  `30`  `40`
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 dv        1     0   0.5 0.667   0.5     1 0.333
# 2 dv        1     0   1   1       0.5     1 0.667
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the quick reply. That solves my problem with the linking of the rows. 
Now I still have the problem that in the resulting column "var" are not yet the names of the variables. I'm sure the problem is that I can't write the variable names in var in my cross_fun function. Any suggestions for resolving the problem in the line?:  
...
mutate(var = "dv") %>% # here I would like to have the {{ DV }} Argument as values of var, but mutate(var = {{ DV }}) or mutate (var = quote(DV)) does'nt work
...

Comment: Yes, change `mutate(var = "dv")` to `mutate(var = DV)`. `"dv"` just gives you the character `"dv"`; `DV` will give you whatever was actually passed to the `DV` argument. btw, I just updated my answer with more unsolicited feedback on your code.